# Flutter listview.builder error Failed assertion: line 1430 pos 14: '_childElements.containsKey(index)': is not true

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-animation

```
 SizedBox(
  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 1.6,
  child: ListView.builder(
    physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
    itemBuilder: (context, index) => Padding(
       padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
       child: PendingContainer(
          pickUpEntity: HomeCubit.get(context).pickUp![index])),
       itemCount: HomeCubit.get(context).pickUp!.length,
       ),
    ),
```

```
package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart': 
Failed assertion: line 1430 pos 14: '_childElements.containsKey(index)': is not true.
```

[image: Error inside the app]

I searched to find any alternative solution but I could not have the answer please help

Comment: Are you sure that pickUp does not return a null value before you start building list?

Comment: provide code of PendingContainer